# Javascript recursive function variable null

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to test out a simple recursive function to make a countdown timer. So far I have this javascript function:

```
setInterval(run_countdown("1"),1000);

function run_countdown(num) {
    var str = document.getElementById(num).innerHTML; 
    if(str === 0){
        str = 59;
        num = num + 1;
        run_countdown(num)
    } 
    var minus = str - 1;
    var res = str.replace(str,minus);
    document.getElementById(num).innerHTML=res;
    return;
};
```

and this is the markup in the browser:

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="6">00</td>
            <td id="5">00</td>
            <td id="4">08</td>
            <td id="3">02</td>
            <td id="2">42</td>
            <td id="1">02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Years</th>
            <th>Months</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Minutes</th>
            <th>Seconds</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run the page in the browser, I get an error in the consol saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" for the very first getElementById. I did an alert on num and it seemed to be passing in ok. Not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: probably just a typo: ` <td id="p">02</td>` should probably be ` <td id="1">02</td>`

Comment: Before adding an answer, I'd just make sure you're running the javascript AFTER you're HTML is generated?

Comment: @basilikum that was just a typo when filling out my question

Comment: ok, next problem: `str = 0` should be `str === 0`

Comment: `setInterval` expects a function.

Comment: You dont have an element by id of 1

Comment: `i = i + 1`? Where's `i` defined?

Comment: Also, html ids should not begin with numbers. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Look carefully at the comment from @elclanrs.  It should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @elclanrs That was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @bluevoodoo1 Yes. I understand that. This was simply for a test

Comment: @bluevoodoo1 Actually `id`s in HTML5 are allowed to begin with a number, the post you've linked is from year 2008.

Comment: You have  a lot of issues here. what are you trying to accomplish?\

Comment: @AlexShilman What issues?

Comment: Your timer is not a correct timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as elchlanrs said, setInterval takes a function reference.  Try

```
setInterval(function(){
  run_countdown("1");
}, 1000);
```

This will wait a full second before calling run_countdown("1"), presumably allowing your document to finish loading before execution which should fix the error.

Comment: that was my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until your page has loaded:

```
document.onload = function() {
    setInterval(run_countdown("1"),1000);
}
```